# Does Amazon Prime video support Dolby Vision on Apple TV?

Tags: appletv, hdr

Amazon Prime video came to Apple TV today. Amazon Prime video supports Dolby Vision, but does it support it on Apple TV. I ask because Amazon Prime video doesn't support all Dolby Vision capable devices.

In my case I have an Apple TV 4K.

Comment: There are many models of AppleTV which one do you have? ATV3, ATV4? ATV4k?

Comment: @IconDaemon ATV4K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of now, it does not. Amazon Prime Video on Apple TV 4K will send HDR10 content, which can be converted to Dolby Vision on the Apple TV itself, or sent directly as HDR10 if the "match content" setting is enabled on your box. Amazon Prime on Apple TV also annoyingly streams 2.1 PCM audio instead of 5.1, though Amazon says this is temporary, and that Dolby Digital Plus audio is coming soon to Apple TV 4K.

For full compatibility, take a look at the supported devices / formats page on Amazon's website:

[Compatible Amazon Video devices and the features available on each device.](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_left_v4_sib?tag=franchiseco0a-20&nodeId=201460880&ie=UTF8)