# Can I Watch Prime Video On Apple TV?

Tags: appletv

I have not figured how to play prime video on Apple TV.

is it possible to watch prime video on Apple TV?

Comment: It is possible on an Apple TV _device_, but not possible in the Apple TV _app_ like you might have on a different device (iPhone, Xbox, smart TV, etc.).

Comment: @jimtut my Apple TV app shows Prime content and always has. I don’t know about smart TV since I prefer dumb ones and Xbox - so your comment might be true if you removed iPhone from the mix. The app and content work as expected for me on all Apple devices and apps for my geo locale in the US.

Comment: Yes, the Apple TV app can indeed show content from Amazon prime and many other external services, but only on iDevices and ATV’s. However you cannot watch Amazon prime content inside the Apple TV app, on any device. If you click on Prime content it will launch the Amazon Prime app on that device.  This is a very different experience than Channels, which are something that you subscribe to within the app and content on that channel is watched directly inside the Apple TV app. Amazon prime is not available as a channel, therefore you cannot watch Prime content directly inside the TV app.

Answer (score 2):

Initially Amazon didn’t have an app for the tv, so I used the iPhone or iPad app to AirPlay that content on my Apple TV. [Now that the app supports tvOS](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/308155/5472), I would start there.

- https://apps.apple.com/us/app/amazon-prime-video/id545519333